# Problem with csquotes and hyperref color links together

Tags: hyperref, csquotes

I have a problem running "csquotes" and "hyperref" with the option `colorlinks` together, producing the error:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \bgroup 
l.13   }
```

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\MakeAutoQuote*{<}{>}

\begin{document}
This is a test!
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? This is on TeXLive 2014 on Linux, fresh install.

Comment: You should move `\MakeAutoQuote*{<}{>}` before loading `hyperref` or, perhaps better, where it is but as argument to `\AtBeginDocument`. Or, best of all, avoid `<` and `>` as quoting characters.

Comment: The first solution proposed does not work, the second does!

Comment: It's quite strange, but I can't reproduce the issue any more.

Comment: What version of hyperref are you using ?

Comment: I ask because I produced it running TeXLive 2014 which has an extremely old version of hyperref (2007/01/06 v6.75l). If you upgrade hyperref the problem goes away!

Comment: As far as I know, the version of `hyperref` on TeX Live 2014 is `2012/11/06 v6.83m`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! You are absolutely right! The version on TeX Live 2014 is 2012/11/06 v6.83m. It was my confusion in one of the systems here. Sorry about that!